# How to avoid a deadlock caused by a thread panic?

Tags: rust, synchronization, deadlock

My server uses a `Barrier` to notify the client when it's safe to attempt to connect. Without the barrier, we risk failing randomly as there is no guarantee that the server socket would have been bound.

Now imagine that the server panics - for instance tries to bind the socket to port 80. The client will be left `wait()`-ing forever. We cannot `join()` the server thread in order to find out if it panicked, because `join()` is a blocking operation - if we `join()` we won't be able to `connect()`.

What's the proper way to do this kind of synchronization, given that the `std::sync` APIs do not provide methods with timeouts?

This is just a MCVE to demonstrate the issue. I had a similar case in a unit test - it was left running forever.

```
use std::{
    io::prelude::*,
    net::{SocketAddr, TcpListener, TcpStream},
    sync::{Arc, Barrier},
};

fn main() {
    let port = 9090;
    //let port = 80;

    let barrier = Arc::new(Barrier::new(2));
    let server_barrier = barrier.clone();

    let client_sync = move || {
        barrier.wait();
    };

    let server_sync = Box::new(move || {
        server_barrier.wait();
    });

    server(server_sync, port);
    //server(Box::new(|| { no_sync() }), port); //use to test without synchronisation

    client(&client_sync, port);
    //client(&no_sync, port); //use to test without synchronisation
}

fn no_sync() {
    // do nothing in order to demonstrate the need for synchronization
}

fn server(sync: Box<Fn() + Send + Sync>, port: u16) {
    std::thread::spawn(move || {
        std::thread::sleep_ms(100); //there is no guarantee when the os will schedule the thread. make it 100% reproducible
        let addr = SocketAddr::from(([127, 0, 0, 1], port));
        let socket = TcpListener::bind(&addr).unwrap();
        println!("server socket bound");
        sync();

        let (mut client, _) = socket.accept().unwrap();

        client.write_all(b"hello mcve").unwrap();
    });
}

fn client(sync: &Fn(), port: u16) {
    sync();

    let addr = SocketAddr::from(([127, 0, 0, 1], port));
    let mut socket = TcpStream::connect(&addr).unwrap();
    println!("client socket connected");

    let mut buf = String::new();
    socket.read_to_string(&mut buf).unwrap();
    println!("client received: {}", buf);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a `Barrier` I would use a [`Condvar`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Condvar.html) here.

To actually solve your problem, I see at least three possible solutions:

1. Use [`Condvar::wait_timeout`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Condvar.html#method.wait_timeout) and set the timeout to a reasonable duration (e.g. 1 second which should be enough for binding to a port)
2. You could use the same method as above, but with a lower timeout (e.g. 10 msec) and check if the `Mutex` is poisoned.
3. Instead of a `Condvar`, you could use a plain [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) (make sure that the `Mutex` is locked by the other thread first) and then use [`Mutex::try_lock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html#method.try_lock) to check if the `Mutex` [is poisoned](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/enum.TryLockError.html#variant.Poisoned)

I think one should prefer solution 1 or 2 over the third one, because you will avoid to make sure that the other thread has locked the `Mutex` first.